# Start a SIP call on a Symbian S60 mobile device

Tags: mobile, symbian, voip, sip, s60

I looking for a way to programmatically start a VOIP call using the SIP stack on a S60 Symbian mobile phone.

Some of the later S60 devices have a built-in SIP client. Is it also possible to access the SIP stack using some S60 library on those devices. Or does anyone know of an external SIP stack that can be used on S60?

Comment: "start a call" as in using the Telephony API to talk to someone? why would you need SIP to do that?

Comment: True, it is possible to start a call using the Telephony API. But I'd like to start the a VoIP call which is not handled by the Telephony API. I've updated the question to clarify that this is about VoIP and not normal phone calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APIs for making VoIP calls do **not** require special access, you merely have to download the SDK plug-in API. See http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Utilizing_Nokia_VoIP_Client for details.

Note that some devices (e.g. some Vodafone N95 variants) have a SIP stack, but not the additional Internet Telephony libraries. On these devices you won't be able to make calls through the APIs detailed in the above link. (Internet Telephony is a lot more than SIP - RTP, RTCP, SDP, on-device audio handling etc.).

Answer (score 0):

These APIs require special access, but [here](http://nds2.content.mosh.nokia.com/entity/6/4452B13D5F854A8DE040050A45306C1B/Developing_3rd_party_VoIP_clients_on_S60_platform_v1_0_en.pdf?c=m&type=6)'s some documentation about them.